# Changing constraints to expand a view in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, anchorpoint, layout-anchor

I have a stack with 2 view inside it, the yellow takes up 70% of the stack and the green the other 30%. I want  to code a button that will upon click:

1. Expand the stack to the top of the screen, which I have done via:

`myStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true`

2. Then make the green box take up the whole stack, so the screen will be completely green

I have done the 70:30 thing with "equal widths constraint like so: [widths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQhj6.jpg)

How may I achieve this functionality and what is the code of resetting everything back to normal? [desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlxIS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change the stackView distribution to be `Fill Proportionally`.
2. Set up width constraints indepedently for each view (with priority = 999, allowed to break). (`0.7 of superview.width` for first & `0.3 of superview.width` for second).
3. Call `firstView.isHidden = true`, it will automatically stretch the secondView to cover stackView in full - **Expanded** state.
4. Call `firstView.isHidden = false`, it will bring you back to **Initial** state.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it is working like intended. How do I make the view go back to its normal height of 250 after I stretch the stack to the top of the screen via: myStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true. This stretches to the top but how do I get it back in the normal height again? of 250

Comment: You need to deactivate the `stackView.top-to-superview.top` constraint. As soon as this is deactivated, it will go back to normal size.